# android inflate view findViewById not work

Tags: android

I have BIG problem with `inflate` and tired.

I Have another layout in my app this is `message` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="369dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/msg"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and when I try to change `msg` text It's failed:

```
View vw = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message, null);

msg = (TextView) vw.findViewById(R.id.msg);

msg.setText("123");

setContentView(R.layout.message);
```

and the app not exception.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `setContentView` via with new View:

```
setContentView(vw);
```

Answer (score 1):

If its fragment you must return vw as your view.

```
Return vw;
```

If its Activity you must set the vw as content view.

```
setContentView(vw);
```

Comment: where is the fragment?

Comment: Fragment is a different class, depends on your class. are you using activity or fragment?

Comment: activity how can I use fragment?

Comment: Fragment is a different class, please refer to here fore more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html